# not getting what's wrong with my code

Tags: java, computer-science

```
public class DigitRange {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String numberstr = args[0];
    int numberint = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int large=0;
    int small=0;
    System.out.println("range of " +numberint + " = "+ Range(numberstr,numberint,large,small));
}

public static int Range (String numberstr, int numberint,int large,int small){
    for(int i=1;i<=numberstr.length();i++){
        int digit = numberint % 10;
    numberint = numberint/10;
    large = Math.max(digit, large) ;
    small = Math.min(digit, small);
    }
    int range = large - small + 1;
    return range; //giving me 9
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code ? I am having a problem with returning the correct value from my method Range. I am returning the value 9 when i should be returning the value 6. I believe i have a logic error there.

NEW problem: 
public class DigitRange {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String numberstr = args[0];
    int numberint = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int max=0;
    int min=9;
    System.out.println("range of " + numberstr + " = "+ Range(numberstr,numberint,max,min));
}
//finds and returns the range
public static int Range (String numberstr, int numberint,int max,int min){
    if(numberint<0){
        Math.abs(numberint);
        for(int i=1;i<=numberstr.length()-1;i++){
            int digit = numberint % 10;
            numberint = numberint/10;
            max = Math.max(digit, max) ;
            min = Math.min(digit, min);
        }
    }
    if(numberint>0){
        for(int i=1;i<=numberstr.length();i++){
            int digit = numberint % 10;
            numberint = numberint/10;
            max = Math.max(digit, max) ;
            min = Math.min(digit, min) ;
        }
        int range = max - min + 1;
        return range;
    }
}
```

}

How can i get the max and min out of the scope of if{} ?

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: range should be 6 ... its the largest number minus the smallest plus one
number is 85643

Comment: Edit your question and put that important information with the question and not buried within comments. Also what have you done to try to debug this? Have you used a debugger (I always wonder why folks hardly bother to do this before coming here)?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I *hope* it's because they're not familiar with it. Same goes for using a profiler.

Comment: @Kayaman What about logging? He is already using it.

Comment: @gian1200 I'm not sure what you mean by that, but yes, logging is an important tool as well. Whether using a real logging framework or just printing to sysout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the smallest and largest digit in the number passed as argument to your code and the difference + 1 is your range, right?

Probably small should be initialized to 9.